# mysql select that returns most recent entry from each person in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come up with a single mySQL query that will take the data below and output the sample output I provided.

Basically what I'm looking for is an output that show only the most recent entry for each person in the table, (their name and the total_points).

The catch here is I only want to show people who have at least 200 points in their most recent entry.  In my example output only jeff and bob would have at least 200 points , but ted would NOT and should not be part on the output.

Is there a way to do this in a single query or would I have to break it out into separate queries?

**Table Structure:**

---

```
person------------date--------------------------------------total_points
jeff-----------------2018-07-16 09:00:00----------------300
bob----------------2018-07-15 09:00:00----------------500
ted-----------------2018-07-09 09:00:00----------------100
jeff-----------------2018-07-09 09:00:00----------------700
bob----------------2018-07-03 09:00:00----------------180
ted-----------------2018-06-10 09:00:00----------------1200
```

**Output:**

---

```
person--------total_points
jeff-------------300
bob------------500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery to get the most recent value:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.person = t.person) and
      t.total_points >= 200;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your query.  is where are t and t2 coming from?

Comment: @Austin . . . `t` is your unnamed table in the question.  `t2` is a table alias, a fundamental part of SQL.